# PHP code doesn't show MySql table

Tags: php

I have used this code to show a table named "me" from a database with "punisher" name.But It doesn't show anything.

Is the problem with my code or another things? I have installed MySql and Apache Web Server in my pc.

Here is the code :

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '********';

$database = 'punisher';
$table = 'me';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Please put this in your code, and reload the page. Then tell us if it says anything. error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: What output are you getting? Are you at least getting the field names?

Comment: No here is what i got : http://uploadtak.com/images/r969_sshot1.png

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked your code a bit,

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = 'password';

$database = 'punisher';
$table = 'me';

mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd) or die("Can't connect to database");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Can't select database");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table) or die("Query to show fields from table failed");

echo "<h1>Table: ".$table."</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>Name: ".$row->name."</td><td>Number: ".$row->number."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Should do the job, if not, please post a screenshot of your table in phpmyadmin.

Post a table screenshot anyways

Comment: @Madivad, no point in removing the password since it's running on localhost.. ;)

Comment: @CLONER I meant take a screenshot fo your phpmyadmin, not of your output

Comment: I opened MySql Command line client and I create a database (punisher) and then i created a table(me) with 2 columns (name&number).

Comment: And have you inserted data into that table?

For example (yourname) with your number?

Comment: I've editted my code, try using this? (replace "password" with your password ofcourse)

Comment: Yes I inserted my name and my number.and using (select * from me) i saw the table

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. I copied & pasted to run on my local and it works ;)

I suggest to investigate your mysql and table setup.